# Regex and Javascript : find word with accents

Tags: javascript, regex, non-ascii-characters

I try to find and stock in HTML paragraphe all the word.

Actually, I have a function like this

```
p.html(function(index, oldHtml) {
return oldHtml.replace(/\b(\w+?)\b/g, '<span>$1</span>');
});
```

But it's only return word without accent.
I test on regex101.com
https://www.regex101.com/r/jS5gW6/1

Any idea ?

Comment: you need to use unicodes..

Comment: Do you need to find *only* words containing accents, or *all* words? Note that part of your problem is that `\w` does not recognize accented characters as 'word' characters, and another part is that `\b` internally uses the definition of `\w` to scan for word boundaries. So, even adding `é` and `ç` to a class with `\w` does not solve everything.

Comment: @Jongware I need to find all words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a character class:

```
oldHtml.replace(/([\wàâêëéèîïôûùüç]+)/gi, '<span>$1</span>');
```

Trying it:

```
var oldHtml = 'kjh À ùp géçhj ùù Çfg';
var res = oldHtml.replace(/([\wàâêëéèîïôûùüç]+)/gi, '<span>$1</span>');
```

gives

```
"<span>kjh</span> <span>À</span> <span>ùp</span> <span>géçhj</span> <span>ùù</span>
```

Çfg"

Comment: How odd -- but thanks for clarifying! I assumed `i` would not 'ignore the case' *because* JS's regex does not support accented characters. I suppose it uses the general `toLowerCase()` underneath, then.

Comment: thank you, it's work... Regex is complicate :-)